# json encode using php not able to get [] brackets

Tags: php, json

here is my code

```
<? 
include '../dbConnect.php';


 $amp=trim($_POST['amp']);
//$amp='AMP8';
//$sql=mysql_query("select tblRepairQueue.ackNo,tblRepairQueue.repairStatus,tblRepairQueue.savedAt from tblRepairQueue,AMPcustomers where AMPcustomers.phone1=tblRepairQueue.phoneNo and AMPcustomers.id='".$amp."'");

$sql=mysql_query("select phone1 from AMPcustomers where id='".$amp."'");
$response = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

$sql_query=mysql_query("select ackNo,repairStatus,savedAt from tblRepairQueue where phoneNo='".$row['phone1']."'");
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql_query)){

    $ackNo=$row1['ackNo'];
$repairStatus=$row1['repairStatus'];
    $savedAt=$row1['savedAt'];

$response[]=array('ackNo'=>$ackNo,'repairStatus'=>$repairStatus,'savedAt'=>$savedAt);
}}
print json_encode($response);

 ?>
```

output m getting as

```
{"ackNo":"26101211236759","repairStatus":"Closed and Complete","savedAt":"2012-10-26 00:55:25",{"ackNo":"031212102614381","repairStatus":"Closed and Complete","savedAt":"2012-12-02 23:05:54"}
```

but i want the output to look like

```
[{"ackNo":"26101211236759","repairStatus":"Closed and Complete","savedAt":"2012-10-26 00:55:25"},{"ackNo":"031212102614381","repairStatus":"Closed and Complete","savedAt":"2012-12-02 23:05:54"}]
```

Can anyone plz help in finding the mistake or what has to be done to get square brackets at the end

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit strange because I have this code:

```
<?php
$array = array();
$array[] = array("ackNo"=>"26101211236759","repairStatus"=>"Closed and Complete","savedAt"=>"2012-10-26 00:55:25");
$array[] = array("ackNo"=>"26101211236780","repairStatus"=>"Closed and Complete","savedAt"=>"2012-10-26 10:55:25");
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

And I get this correct form:

```
[{"ackNo":"26101211236759","repairStatus":"Closed and Complete","savedAt":"2012-10-26 00:55:25"},{"ackNo":"26101211236780","repairStatus":"Closed and Complete","savedAt":"2012-10-26 10:55:25"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should indeed output `[{...},...]`. So we can't really tell you what went wrong on your side. check the structure of the `$response` variable before the conversion to Json to see what went wrong.

Note that the code allows SQL injection. You must change it so that the parameters `$amp` and `$row['phone1']` are escaped in the SQL queries. Even if you're relying on magic qoutes now, this solution is not future-proof (now-proof really) as support for this is was removed in PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck it can not give you the output like that `{"ackNo":"26101211236759","repairStatus":"Closed and Complete","savedAt":"2012-10-26 00:55:25",{"ackNo":"031212102614381","repairStatus":"Closed and Complete","savedAt":"2012-12-02 23:05:54"}`

as it is creating an array of array so it can not print like that.

It will always print like

```
[{"ackNo":"26101211236759","repairStatus":"Closed and Complete","savedAt":"2012-10-26 00:55:25"},{"ackNo":"031212102614381","repairStatus":"Closed and Complete","savedAt":"2012-12-02 23:05:54"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have written should work:

http://ideone.com/ErV9fr

```
// How many to add
$response_count=3;

// Your response, just templated
$response_template=array(
    'response_number'=>0,
    'ackNo'=>'dffdgd',
    'repairStatus'=>'$repairStatus',
    'savedAt'=>'$savedAt'
);

// Your empty response array
$response = array();

for($i=0;$i<$response_count;$i++) {
    $response_template['response_number'] = $i; // Set the 'response number' to the     itteration.
    $response[]= $response_template; // Add the template to the collection
}

print json_encode($response);
```

Result:

[{"response_number":0,"ackNo":"dffdgd","repairStatus":"$repairStatus","savedAt":"$savedAt"},{"response_number":1,"ackNo":"dffdgd","repairStatus":"$repairStatus","savedAt":"$savedAt"},{"response_number":2,"ackNo":"dffdgd","repairStatus":"$repairStatus","savedAt":"$savedAt"}]

In addition to this, you should sanitize your $amp variable.  In it's current form it would be trivial for a user to escape your query and execute an arbitrary query against your DB.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php